# Probability generation function example

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

let all the $X_i$ (for $1 \leq  i \leq n$) be i.i.d. non-negative int-valued rand. variables. let each $X_i$ with probability generating function G(s), determine the generation function of the sum of $S_n = X_1 + 2X_2 + · · · + nX_n$

This is what I did so far:

$G(S_n) = E[s^{S_n}] = E(s^{X_1 + 2X_2 + · · · + nX_n})$

$G(S_n) = E(s^{X_1}s^{2X_2}...s^{nX_n})$

since iid

$G(S_n) = E(s^{X_1})E(s^{2X_2})...E(s^{nX_n})$

what would be the next step please.

Comment: Note for example that $E(s^{3X_3})=G(s^3)$.

Comment: Additionally, try more rigour in the notations, $G(S_n)$ is absurd and should be $G_{S_n}(s)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so would the final answer just be:
$G_{S_n}(s) = G_{X_1}(s)G_{X_2}(s^2)...G_{X_n}(s^n)$

Comment: It is $G(s)G(s^2)\cdots G(s^n)$.

Comment: @Did thanks +1.

Comment: @AndréNicolas because of the iid